# Scraping JSON data from e-commerce Ajax site with Python

Tags: python, json, ajax, beautifulsoup, response

Previously, I posted a question on how do I get the data from an AJAX website which is from this link: [Scraping AJAX e-commerce site using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401612/scraping-ajax-e-commerce-site-using-python/54402211?noredirect=1#comment95695855_54402211)

I understand a bit on how to get the response which is using the chrome F12 in Network tab and do some coding with python to display the data. But I barely can't find the specific API url for it. The JSON data is not coming from a URL like the previous website, but it is in the Inspect Element in Chrome F12.

[image]
[image]

---

1. My real question actually is how do I get **ONLY the JSON data** using BeautifulSoup or anything related to it? After I can get only the JSON data from the application/id+json then I will convert it to be a JSON data that python can recognize so that I can display the products into table form.
2. One more problem is after several time I run the code, the JSON data is missing. I think the website will block my IP address. How to I solve this problem?

---

Here is the website link:

*https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page=1&q=h370m&sort=priceasc*

Here is my code

> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import requests
>
> page_link =
>   'https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page=1&q=h370m&sort=priceasc'
>
> page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
>
> page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
>
> print(page_content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `find` method with the pointer to your `<script>` tag with the attr `type=application/json`

Then you can use the `json` package to load the value inside a dict

Here is a code sample:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json

page_link = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page=1&q=h370m&sort=priceasc'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = soup(page_response.text, "html.parser")

json_tag = page_content.find('script',{'type':'application/json'})
json_text = json_tag.get_text()
json_dict = json.loads(json_text)
print(json_dict)
```

**EDIT:** My bad, I didn't see you search `type=application/ld+json` attr
As it seems to have several `<script>`with this attr, you can simply use the `find_all` method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json

page_link = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page=1&q=h370m&sort=priceasc'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = soup(page_response.text, "html.parser")

json_tags = page_content.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})
for jtag in json_tags:
    json_text = jtag.get_text()
    json_dict = json.loads(json_text)
    print(json_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It works. But after 3 times running the same code, it won't work anymore. Does it mean the website is blocking my ip?

Comment: How do I prevent the ip block? Use selenium?

Comment: I don't know if it's an ip block, and don't know how to prevent it

Comment: It's okay sir. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I barely understand your solution. Can you help me out on the code?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse data from HTML manually from your `Soup` as other websites will restrict their `json API` from other parties.

You can find out more details here in the documentation:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/